# ASP.NET Core Configuration Binder how to debug

Tags: c#, configuration, asp.net-core

I'm moving json configuration from custom-parsed to Microsoft.Configuration.Extensions.Binder thing. I keep getting null when binding with Get or GetValue and I'm a bit lost on how to debug that. I already changed my configuration objects to what I think they should look like based on json, but no luck. The objects are more complex than the trivial examples in the docs (those work of course).

I'd like to have some information like "I'm trying to set that property of your object but it's not there" or "I'd like to assign that json thing to a property, but this json thing is not there".

Any ideas how I can debug that?